# Nonmaximality of tensor product $R \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: ring-theory, tensor-products, p-adic-number-theory

Let $R$ be a ring (all rings are commutative with a unity), which is also a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $n$, and consider the ring $S = R \otimes_\mathbb{Z} \mathbb{Z}_p$, where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ denotes the $p$-adic integers. Then, $S$ is a free rank $n$ $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module. Suppose that $S$ is strictly contained in a ring $S'$, which is also a rank $n$ $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module (and a $\mathbb{Z}_p$ algebra). I want to show that then $R$ is strictly contained in some ring $R'$ which is also a rank $n$ $\mathbb{Z}$-module, with an index divisible by $p$.

I have managed to show the converse of the question above, but this direction seems harder. Somehow if $S \subset S'$, one should be able to extract a free rank $n$ $\mathbb{Z}$-module from $S'$, but I cannot see how to accomplish this.

The context of this question is the paper "Orbital L-functions for the Space of Binary Cubic Forms" by Taniguchi and Thorne. There it is stated on p.1341 (a cubic ring is an algebra that is a free rank 3 module over some other ring as described above with n=3)

"We say that a cubic ring over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is maximal if it is not isomorphic to a proper subring of another cubic ring. We say that a cubic ring R over $\mathbb{Z}$ is maximal at $p$ if it is not contained in another cubic ring with finite index divisible by $p$, or equivalently if $R \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ is maximal as a cubic ring over $\mathbb{Z}_p$."

Comment: I guess rings "contained" in each other here do not have to share the same unit? Also, I guess you want the "inclusion" $S \hookrightarrow S'$ to be induced via tendering by the "inclusion" $R \hookrightarrow R'$ --- otherwise there's no real connection to the setting, and any such extension would do.

Comment: That all being said and hopefully clarified, I guess the elementary divisor theorem would be the first crucial step here.

Comment: The containment should be in the sense of being a subring (subalgebra even), so they should share unity. I am not sure what you mean by tendering. I will add some context in the statement of the question.

Comment: @CrackedBauxite the term "tendering" in the first comment was a typo for "tensoring".

Comment: If the containment of the "S-rings" were induced by such a tensor product then I guess my question would be almost trivial. I am not at all familiar with the subject so I cannot say if this is what the authors meant.

Comment: "tensoring" indeed, darn autocorrect. OK, same units then, I had just focussed first on the case $n=1$ where that is impossible, but for $n \ge 2$ I see now what kinds of rings we're interested in here (like orders vs. maximal orders in number fields).

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes, those are the kind of rings the rest of the paper is about. I am starting to wonder if they are only considering extensions of $S$ of the form $R' \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p$ as you mentioned earlier. That would simplify matters.